# Intel 240GB installed and 15GB of partition created automatically

Tags: windows, ssd

I got Intel 335 series 240GB. Installed it in my laptop using Intel Migration Software. During the process, it has created a partition with size 15GB.

This partition is not assigned to any drive letter thus not visible in normal use.

What is this partition for? 15GB is quite huge considering it is in SSD. Can I just remove it and merge it to primary partition?

Comment: what operating system you installed ?

Comment: What OS are you using, are you migrating a partition or makin a new one? If you are migrating, what is the size of the previous drive?

Answer (score 0):

Windows automatically creates a reserve partition(not sure if it's 10 GB in size though) 
would be lot better if you post a screenshot too.

Comment: If your system partition of larger than a certain size (don't remember what exactly) windows will create a 100 MB partition as the boot partition.